# How to use Generics Result with Traits?

Tags: rust

I'm fairly new in this. I try to learn how to implement `Copyable` trait to `MyDocument` struct. Each struct which implements `Copyable` had to define the `copy()` function which takes the struct as parameter and another string parameter. The `copy` function returns the original document with `Result` and error possibility in it.

```
// Copyable can be applied to any variant of Document struct, hence T represents the struct
trait Copyable {
    fn copy<T, E>(&self, name: String) -> Result<T, E>;
}

struct MyDocument {
    name: String,
}
```

This is the implementation that I try

```
impl Copyable for MyDocument {
    /// this is error, How to implement copy function 
    /// without making rust thinks that <MyDocument, and DocumentError are type parameters ?
    fn copy<MyDocument, DocumentError>(&self, name: String) -> Result<MyDocument, DocumentError> {
        let result = MyDocument { name };
        Ok(result)
    }
}


// impl Copyable for MyDocument {
//     if I omit the <T, E> parameters, it throws an error that 
//     method `copy` has 0 type parameters but its trait 
//     declaration has 2 type parameters
//     fn copy(&self, name: String) -> Result<MyDocument, DocumentError> {
//         let result = MyDocument { name };
//         Ok(result)
//     }
// }
```

.. and how I try to call the `copy` function from the doc object:

```
fn main() {
    let doc = MyDocument {
        name: "Document".to_string(),
    };

    let result: Result<MyDocument, DocumentError> = doc.copy("Document".to_string());
    
    match result {
        Ok(value) => println!("Document edited: {}", value),
        Err(error) => println!("Error: {}", error),
    }
}
```

But the code above returns error:

```
error[E0574]: expected struct, variant or union type, found type parameter `MyDocument`
  --> src\main.rs:11:22
   |
5  | struct MyDocument {
   |        ---------- you might have meant to refer to this struct
...
10 |     fn copy<MyDocument, DocumentError>(&self, name: String) -> Result<MyDocument, DocumentError> {
   |             ---------- found this type parameter
11 |         let result = MyDocument { name };
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^ not a struct, variant or union type
```

How to rearrange the code above so I can implement `Copyable` to any struct that I want using generics ?

Comment: Your calling code expects a `Result<String, String>` but your implementation (attempts to) return a `Result<MyDocument, DocumentError>`.  Which do you actually want?

Comment: oh sorry... it's a typo

Comment: my goal is to implement a function from a trait that returns a possibility of an error in it. (`Result<MyDocument, Error>`)

Comment: it could be a generic `io::error` or custom implementation error type. My point is how to declare that I want to implement a function that returns "Return<>" without Rust confuses it with type parameters

Comment: what's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a trait, there are essentially three kinds of place that you can specify type parameters:

```rust
trait Copyable<A> {
    type B;

    fn copy<C>(...);
}
```

One way to understand the difference between these type parameters is to consider who gets to choose what concrete type they have in a given situation:

- `A` is a *generic type parameter of the trait* - its concrete type is specified by the implementor, and many different types can be specified for a given struct.
- `B` is an *associated type parameter of the trait* - its concrete type is specified by the implementor, but each implementing struct may have only that one type (for any given combination of generic type parameters `A`); and
- `C` is a *generic type parameter of the trait function `copy`* - its concrete type is opaque to the implementor, as it is instead determined by calling code when the function is called (and may be determined differently at each call site).

In your case, the calling code requires `T` and `E` to be `String`.  The fact that you have named the type parameters `MyDocument` and `DocumentError` in the trait implementation is confusing, but they are still just placeholder names.

Assuming you have a type `DocumentError` defined elsewhere, I think you want to use `Self` together with an associated type for the error:

```rust
trait Copyable: Sized {
    type Error;
    fn copy(&self, name: String) -> Result<Self, Self::Error>;
}

impl Copyable for MyDocument {
    type Error = DocumentError;
    fn copy(&self, name: String) -> Result<Self, DocumentError> {
        let result = MyDocument { name };
        Ok(result)
    }
}
```

However, in order for your `println` invocations to then work as-is, you will need to implement `Display` for both `MyDocument` and `DocumentError`.

Comment: How do I decide what struct / type I should use for B? Why using Error and not using MyDocument for B?

Comment: Can I assume: "If a function with `Return<TypeA, TypeB>` then B in this case will always the second parameter or `TypeB` ?

Comment: @DennyHiu: In my suggestion above, `Error` is the associated type name defined by the trait author; and `DocumentError` is the concrete type used for that `Error` by `MyDocument`.  You can name the associated type whatever you want, but the concrete type selected must be that which you intend to use.

Comment: wait... the line `fn copy(&self, name: String) -> Result<Self, Self::Error>` in the trait definition gives an error `the size for values of type `Self` cannot be known at compilation time`

Comment: Ah, apologies.  You will need to add a `Sized` bound to the trait definition: `trait Copyable: Sized { ... }`.

Comment: I see.... so `type B` is a placeholder. It's not real/concrete yet until the implementation. It's similar to generics in function, then why we need to use this instead of regular "generics"? What if I had to return an `Option<>` instead of `Result<>`? Do I need to use this scheme too?

Comment: You'd use `Result` instead of `Option` when there's some runtime state that you wish to return to the caller in the failing (error) case.  If there's never any such runtime state then indeed you probably just want an `Option`.